# ssh connecting from macOS to ubuntu refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx

I am trying to connect to my PC (ubuntu) from my MacBook using ssh

When I run:

```
ssh leo@192.168.0.22
```

It connects. However if I try to use my public IP it says

> ssh: connect to host xx.x.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

I have tried changing the port to port 2222 and the connection is still refused, only using the public IP address.

Comment: Home networking questions are off topic here. You may be able to get help with home networking on our sister site [su].

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is connecting to my work Network, this is not my home network

Comment: OK, then please describe the network and the device that answers to the global IP address.

Comment: Did you do port forwarding for it?